# How to print a 2D array with varying sized cells?

Tags: java

I have a 2-D array where each cell is a Set. 
In each set is a different size, say for example, ranging from 0 to 5.

I want to print out the 2-D array in a format such that it's easily readable.

Example

```
HashSet<String>[][] schedule = (HashSet<String>[][]) new HashSet[3][5];
schedule[0][0].add("A");
schedule[0][0].add("B");
schedule[0][0].add("C");

schedule[0][2].add("D");
schedule[0][2].add("E");

schedule[1][0].add("F");
schedule[1][1].add("G");

schedule.print();
```

will produce

```
-----------------
| A |   | D | | |
| B |   | E | | |
| C |   |   | | |
-----------------
| F | G |   | | |
-----------------
|   |   |   | | |
-----------------
```

obviously without the '-' and '|', but you get the point.

The only viable solution I can think of is creating and remembering the iterator for each column (so remembering 5 iterators at the same time) and iterating through each column, outputting one element at a time until there are no more elements in any of the iterators.

One problem is that in the case of G, it expands the second column even though there are not any values in the first row, second column. I can get around this by buffering each column with tabs.

Obviously this hack does not scale with additional columns, so I was wondering if there were any cute tricks that I might have forgotten.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With a few modifications to the code (you forgot to instantiate the positions in the array!), you can definitely print out the jagged sets.

Hint:  Make use of the `iterator()` method that's provided with the `HashSet`.  An iterator moves over a collection of objects, returning one at a time, then pausing until it's invoked again, or there's nothing left to iterate over.   You can find more information about iterators in general at [Wikipedia's Iterator article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator).

Using this, you can gather up the results in each HashSet inside of a String (in any way you desire), and print them out at the end.

Code Snippet:

```
Iterator first = schedule[0][0].iterator();
Iterator second = schedule[0][2].iterator();
// And so forth


String firstResult = "";
String secondResult = "";
// And so forth


while (first.hasNext()) {
    firstResult += first.next() + "\t";
    if (!first.hasNext()) {
        firstResult += "\n";
        }
    }
while (second.hasNext()) {
    secondResult += second.next() + "\t";
    if (!second.hasNext()) {
    secondResult += "\n";
    }
}
// And so forth

System.out.print(firstResult + secondResult + someResult + anotherResult);
```

Filling in the blanks is an exercise for the reader.

With this, the result is as follows:

```
A   B   C   
D   E   
F   
G
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I mentioned in my question that I was already considering using an Iterator for each column, and printing them out sequentially. However as you just showed, it prints them left-right instead of top-down like I drew out. Additionally, for me to manually create an iterator whenever there is a new column is not good practice, because if I wanted to add another column, I'd have to create yet another iterator, violating the DRY principle.